# Files which tell that someone has accessed your computer

Tags: security, history, logs

I know `/var/log/auth.log` shows who has been using sudo commands and `/home/myusername/.bash_history` shows command line commands. I would like to know if there are any more files similar to these 2 files in Ubuntu that can be used to show that someone else may have accessed to your computer?